# How to install Lubuntu on iMac PowerPC G5

Tags: system-installation, lubuntu, powerpc

Is it possible to install Lubuntu on iMac PowerPC G5 using a USB? I created an bootable USB with Lubuntu image using unetbootin, inserted to the iMac, restarted it holding down Option key but the USB image did not appear.

Comment: @M.Becerra: That question only contains answers for x86 and x86_64 architecture systems. However OP's system has a PowerPC architecture.